# Jquery set select option by .val() does not fire on('change', )

Tags: javascript, jquery

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/38604mqg/2/)

```
<select id="panel" >
    <option value=1>One</option>
    <option value=2>Two</option>
    <option value=3>Three</option>
</select> 
<button id="button">Click me</button> <br> 

$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#panel').val(3); 
}); 
$('#panel').on('change',function(){
  alert('Hi'); 
});
```

Does anybody know how to get those thing works?

Comment: Things actually work as they are designed. Think about a situation when you programmatically change a value in an onchange-handler, that change would trigger a new onchange, the value is changed again ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Additional you can use [**.trigger()**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

> Description: Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the
>   matched elements for the given event type.

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#panel').val(3).trigger("change");
});
$('#panel').on('change', function() {
  alert('Hi');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="panel">
  <option value=1>One</option>
  <option value=2>Two</option>
  <option value=3>Three</option>
</select>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<!--click will change the select. But it doesnt fire the on change function. -->
```

Comment: between `.trigger('change')` and `change()` which one is better?

Comment: In your example is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fire the event manually,

```
$('#panel').val(3).change();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/38604mqg/3/)

Answer (score 1):

In your case it won't trigger change event, it is assignment, you have to call change event like. Change as follows 
You have to use like
HTML:

```
<select class="panel" >
                                                                                   <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
                                                                                </select> 
<button id="button">Click me</button> <!--click will change the select. But it doesnt fire the on change function. -->
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.panel').val(3);
    $( ".panel" ).change();
});
 $( ".panel" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```